# Maximum delay between n photons for multi-photon ionization

Tags: non-linear-optics

Given an IR laser with intensities that allow for a Keldysh parameter smaller than 1 in a given sample. I was wondering, what is the allowed timely separation distance between two IR photons such that multi-photon ionization can be probable. In other words, how close to each other need they be to enable a multi-photon process?

I found in [1], that the "dielectronic interaction time" is on the order of 140as for helium. There, this time-scale is estimated based on time-dependent Schrödinger equation simulations. Nevertheless, can I assume this to be a characteristic time-scale for multi-photon processes in helium?

---

Edit after first comment, for more clarity

Maybe mentioning the laser setting was not the best way to question my question. Imagine a setting with only two photons. How close to each other in the time domain would they need to be to "act as one photon".

> [1] Foumouo, E., Antoine, P., Bachau, H. & Piraux, B. Attosecond
>   time-scale analysis of the dynamics of two-photon double ionization of
>   helium. New J. Phys. (2008). doi:10.1088/1367-2630/10/2/025017

Comment: Multi-photon ionization (or formation of Rydberg states) was doable 30+ years ago with femptosecond lasers.

Comment: yes, if you have a lot of photons, some will be close enough to each other. But imagine you only have two photons. How close would they need to be? I'll add this to my question for better clarity.